# QML Image Element > Retina/HiDPI support for network based images

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, retina-display, hidpi

Image element of the QtQuick supports HiDPI images automatically as you know. For example it can loads `@2x` images in the iOS and MacOS platforms. Same code works OK on the Android platform.
There is a section in the official documentation that talked about [network transparency](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtqml-documents-networktransparency.html).
**But the Image element doesn't loads HiDPI version images from my server.**

Is this a bug?
How can I handle this problem to load high dpi images? Is there any official suggested way?

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 900
    height: 520
    Image {
        id: img
        z: 10000
        source: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/images/banner-1.jpg" //<-- not loads @2x version automatically
        width: 320; height: 205  //<-- also I need to specify a size otherwise it will be so big
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to load the image from resource instead of network?

Comment: yeah. It works fine. Also local images works perfect. but network based images not works correctly.

Comment: But is `banner-1.jpg` loaded? Can you check with Wireshark is `@2x` requested at all?

Comment: Yes `banner-1.jpg` loaded. I will use wireshark to check that asap.